haproxy as reverseproxy ssl offloading with two apllications on port 443
I am experiencing some issues with HAProxy running as a reversproxy and redirecting traffic to two different applicarions on port 443.
Application2 is working fine with the configuration below.
Appllication1 causes some minor trouble. Typing in the browser in order to access the domain :“domain.com/application1 2” I do get a Time Out Error and the address in the browser changes to domain.com:82/application1. Were 82 the desired port of the backend and the application1 is listening on.
Now it becomes a little strange to me. Deleting now the “:82” in “domain.com:82/application1” lets me access the application1 in the webbroser. I assume that I messed someting in some line the redirecting command, proxy protocol or ssl offloading up, but I do not see where.
One restriction is, that i need to log the originating IP.
Below my configuration of haproxy and nginx:
haproxy:
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp

        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        option forwardfor header X-Forwarded-For

        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontend http-in
        bind :80
        mode http

        option forwardfor header X-Forwarded-For
        option httplog

        acl is_letsencrypt path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/

        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } !is_letsencrypt
        use_backend be_letsencrypt if is_letsencrypt


frontend https_in
        bind *:443
        option http-server-close

        acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
        acl is_application1 req.ssl_sni -i domain.com

        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if tls

        use_backend recir_application1 if is_application1
        use_backend recir_application2 if !{ req.ssl_hello_type 1 } !{ req.len 0 }


backend be_letsencrypt
        mode http
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:81


backend recir_application1
        server loopback-for-tls abns@haproxy-application1 send-proxy

backend recir_application2
        server loopback-for-tls abns@haproxy-default send-proxy

frontend ssl-default
        bind abns@haproxy-default accept-proxy
        use_backend be_application2


frontend application1
        mode http
        bind abns@haproxy-application1 accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/domain.com/haproxy.pem
        use_backend be_application1


backend be_application2
        server localhost 127.0.0.1:4545


backend be_application1
       mode http
       server localhost 127.0.0.1:82 send-proxy

and nginx:
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:82 proxy_protocol;
    listen [::]:82 proxy_protocol;
    server_name localhost mydomain.com;

# HSTS settings
    # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
    # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
    # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
    # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
    # could take several months.
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;


    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    # rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /webapplication1/public.php?service=host-meta last;
    # rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /webapplication1/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    location ^~ /.well-known {
        # The rules in this block are an adaptation of the rules
        # in `.htaccess` that concern `/.well-known`.

        location = /.well-known/carddav { return 301 /remote.php/dav/; }
        location = /.well-known/caldav  { return 301 /remote.php/dav/; }

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
        location /.well-known/pki-validation    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }

        # Let webapplication1's API for `/.well-known` URIs handle all other
        # requests by passing them to the front-end controller.
        return 301 /index.php$request_uri;
    }
    location ^~ /webapplication1 {
        # set max upload size and increase upload timeout:
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        client_body_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+x>

        # Pagespeed is not supported by webapplication1, so if your server is built
        # with the `ngx_pagespeed` module, uncomment this line to disable it.
        #pagespeed off;

        # The settings allows you to optimize the HTTP2 bandwitdth.
        # See https://blog.cloudflare.com/delivering-http-2-upload-speed-improvements/
        # for tunning hints
        client_body_buffer_size 512k;

        # HTTP response headers borrowed from webapplication1 `.htaccess`
        add_header Referrer-Policy                   "no-referrer"       always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options            "nosniff"           always;
        add_header X-Download-Options                "noopen"            always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options                   "SAMEORIGIN"        always;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"              always;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag                      "noindex, nofollow" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection                  "1; mode=block"     always;

        # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        # Set .mjs and .wasm MIME types
        # Either include it in the default mime.types list
        # and include that list explicitly or add the file extension
        # only for webapplication1 like below:
        include mime.types;
        types {
        text/javascript js mjs;
        application/wasm wasm;
        }

        # Specify how to handle directories -- specifying `/webapplication1/index.php$request_uri`
        # here as the fallback means that Nginx always exhibits the desired behaviour
        # when a client requests a path that corresponds to a directory that exists
        # on the server. In particular, if that directory contains an index.php file,
        # that file is correctly served; if it doesn't, then the request is passed to
        # the front-end controller. This consistent behaviour means that we don't need
        # to specify custom rules for certain paths (e.g. images and other assets,
        # `/updater`, `/ocm-provider`, `/ocs-provider`), and thus
        # `try_files $uri $uri/ /webapplication1/index.php$request_uri`
        # always provides the desired behaviour.
        index index.php index.html /webapplication1/index.php$request_uri;

        # Rule borrowed from `.htaccess` to handle Microsoft DAV clients
        location = /webapplication1 {
            if ( $http_user_agent ~ ^DavClnt ) {
                return 302 /webapplication1/remote.php/webdav/$is_args$args;
            }
        }

        # Rules borrowed from `.htaccess` to hide certain paths from clients
        location ~ ^/webapplication1/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)(?:$|/)    { return 404; }
        location ~ ^/webapplication1/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console)                  { return 404; }

        # Ensure this block, which passes PHP files to the PHP process, is above the blocks
        # which handle static assets (as seen below). If this block is not declared first,
        # then Nginx will encounter an infinite rewriting loop when it prepends
        # `/webapplication1/index.php` to the URI, resulting in a HTTP 500 error response.
        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
            # Required for legacy support
            rewrite ^/webapplication1/(?!index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+|.+\/richdocume>

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;

            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;         # Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;     # Enable pretty urls
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;

            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;

            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|jpg|ico|wasm|tflite|map)$ {
            try_files $uri /webapplication1/index.php$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers
            # Again use 'proxy_set_header' (not 'add_header') as the headers have to be passed through a proxy.
            proxy_set_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
            proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            proxy_set_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            proxy_set_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            proxy_set_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            proxy_set_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;


            location ~ \.wasm$ {
                default_type application/wasm;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.woff2?$ {
            try_files $uri /webapplication1/index.php$request_uri;
            expires 7d;         # Cache-Control policy borrowed from `.htaccess`
            access_log off;     # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        }

        # Rule borrowed from `.htaccess`
        location /webapplication1/remote {
            return 301 /webapplication1/remote.php$request_uri;
        }

        location /webapplication1 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /webapplication1/index.php$request_uri;
        }
    }
}

thank you for your help
Krischan
